# Why is my c++ program crashing?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int m,n;
vector<vector<int> > name(m,vector<int>(n));
int main()
{
    cin>>m>>n;
    for ( int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for( int j=0;j<n;j++)
            cin>>name[i][j];
    }
}
```

Every time I give the input `m` and `n`, it crashes! What I am trying to do is to give the input to a 2 dimensional array of `m` rows and `n` columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialize your vector (or resize it) *after* you read the values for `m` and `n`.  As you have it, `m` and `n` are 0* when the vector is initialized, so the size of the vector is 0.

<sub>*this is only the case because you placed them at global scope. if placed in a function, they would be uninitialized, and it would be undefined behavior to use their values</sub>

Comment: what could be the solution to this problem?

Comment: @Aradhya: Did I not already say?  Initialize your vector (that is, create it) *after* you read the values for `m` and `n` from `cin`, inside the `main` function.

Comment: what if I want to use this vector in some other function?

Comment: @Aradhya: Preferrably, pass it by reference to that function. Otherwise, you can keep it global, but [resize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) it once you have the needed values.

Answer (score 5):

Because of you have run out of bounds.

The `name` vector is  global variable, so it is initialised at the moment of program starting, even before `main` function. Also integer global variables are initialised with `0` in C++. So the `name` vector has zero size.

After reading `n` and `m` values you need to resize the vector.

Answer (score 1):

```
Error is you are trying to access the index out of bound
```

Because your name is not a 2D vector.

use this code instead to make `name` a 2D vector.

```
vector < vector <int> > name;
vector<int > col;
int r, c;
void main()
{

    cin >> r;
    cin >> c;
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
    {
        col.push_back(i);//push i to col just to make it size of columns needed
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        name.push_back(col);//pushing vector col of size c into name to 
        //make it a 2D vecotr
    }
    //now name is a 2D vector with r rows of each c column
    cout << "\nNow Enter values";
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            cin >> name[i][j];//input values
        }
    }

    getch();


}
```